# Java: Parse string argument to array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method which accepts strings as an argument. Now, I need to convert the string arguments to java array as an argument.

This is the Java code:

```
private static Class<?> convertToType(String par1) throws Exception {
    var string = par1.trim();
    //System.out.println("the string is: " + par1);
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(string);
        return int.class;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }

    try {
        Double.parseDouble(string);
        return double.class;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }

    try {
        if (string.toLowerCase().equals("true") || string.toLowerCase().equals("false")) {
            Boolean.parseBoolean(string);
            return boolean.class;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }

    try {
        if (string.charAt(0) == '"' && string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == '"') {
            return String.class;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    try {
        return parseToEnum(string).getClass();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    throw new Exception();
}
```

This the sample method which the method calls:

```
getA(1,2,3, {4,5,6});
```

The values in the `{4,5,6}` represents the array in this case. Whereas 1,2,3 represents integer.

When I call the method getA, the program will call the convertToType method to convert the arguments to the respective datatypes. Currently, I already able to parse the string to int, double, boolean and enum as well. But I am not sure how to parse it to an array object.

My current code execution it get java.lang.exception at the convertToType method.

Comment: often you need some methos such as `String.split`

Comment: @LeiYang can you please help me out by providing a sample for my current issue.

Comment: can you provide function declaration of `getA`?

Comment: @LeiYang its a void getA(int a, int b, int length, boolean[] data);

Comment: what's relationship of `getA` and `convertToType`, can you post the code?